# ZK listbox's forEach and dynamic @load

Tags: java, zk

I am trying to generate variable number of `listbox`'es in my template:

```
<listbox forEach="${vm.columns}" model="@load(vm.getData(each))">
    <listhead>
        <listheader label="column${each}" width="260px" />
    </listhead>
</listbox>
```

And the ViewModel (simplified) looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel {

    private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 3;

    private List<Integer> columns = new ArrayList<>();

    @Init
    public void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_COUNT; i++) {
            columns.add(i);
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(List<Integer> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public List<Picture> getData(Integer pos) {
        System.out.println("GET DATA = " + pos);
            // rest of the code ...
    }
}
```

So the generating part works fine, I can see 3 listboxes generated, with column titles "column0", "column1" and "column3" accordingly in each. But when I investigate logs I see that `getData` method gets called 3 times, but always with argument = 0:

```
2013-10-15T21:16:55.758+0200|INFO: GET DATA = 0
2013-10-15T21:16:55.847+0200|INFO: GET DATA = 0
2013-10-15T21:16:55.849+0200|INFO: GET DATA = 0
```

Maybe someone could explain, why using variable `${each}` in `listheader` works fine, but not within `@load` expression?

Is there a way how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it like that:

```
<vlayout children="@load(vm.columns)">
        <template name="children" var="lb">
            <listbox model="@load(vm.getData(lb))">
                <listhead>
                    <listheader label="@load('column'.concat(lb))" width="260px" />
                </listhead>
            </listbox>
        </template>
</vlayout>
```